# Is there a way to loop over cells of a particular color in a column?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a column (column L) in a spreadsheet in which there are many entries with some duplicate values in that column. Each "group" of duplicate values is colored in a unique color. So i have many colors in my column each of which refers to one group of duplicate values. I have to go through every "Group" so all the cells colored with the same color and do some computation. However, i don't know how to loop through all the cells that are from the same color in a column.

I would really be happy if you could help me with that :)

Comment: do you use conditional formatting?

Comment: You would be looking at the `interior` of the cell.  This could be via `rgb`, `color`, etc.  Do you have any code you've tried thusfar?  That would be helpful in giving a more direct answer, as "how do you do this?" would be considered subjective and not appropriate for this forum intended to answer *objective* questions.

Comment: You can sort by color, maybe this will simplify your problem

Comment: Can you post a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: You can also try to use the `Find`-command and define the color that you search with `Application.FindFormat`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column L
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

        'Set array starting from row 2 to LastRow of column L
        arr = .Range("L2:L" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            If .Range("L" & i).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then

                For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                    If (.Range("L" & j).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone) And (i <> j) Then

                        If .Range("L" & i).Interior.Color = .Range("L" & j).Interior.Color Then

                            If .Range("N" & i).Value = "" Then
                                .Range("N" & i).Value = "Cell L" & i & " has the same background color with cell/s L" & j
                            Else
                                .Range("N" & i).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value & ", L" & j
                            End If

                        End If

                    End If

                Next j

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]